# Set up iOS push notification for multiple test environments

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

We are using **Apple Developer Enterprise Program**.
I want to test the push notification on multiple test environments, currently we have four. 
I have no problems to generate one Production SSL Certificate per environment but I didn’t find the way to add/attach them to the same App ID. Currently Apple accepted only two.
How should I proceed to test the Push Notification on multiple test environments (test1, test2, …)?
Should I create one App ID and SSL Certificate per environment?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why can you not and why are you not using the same set of credentials for each environment? You wouldn't be able to create multiple sets of credentials anyway.

Answer (score 0):

We currently have our application set up with three targets, one for Dev, Staging and Production.

The targets each have a different bundle identifier, so we can generate separate push certificates for each one.

Then, we're using a push provider, Pushwoosh, that allows multiple applications on the account, (not sure if the free account supports multiple apps, but you could create multiple free accounts,) that lets us target which instance of the app we want with pushes from their console or from our back end through their API.

Comment: Hi Eric,

Thanks for you feedback.
Taking in account that I have four targets, I think to set up as follows:
I will create one bundle id per two targets(it's possible to have two production certificates by one app ID).
Test 1 and Test 2 env = bundleid_test_12 + prod_certif_1+prod_certif_2
Test 3 and Test 4 env = bundleid_test_34 + prod_certif_3+prod_certif_4

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

No, there are only APNS environments - production and sandbox.

Having said that, you can have n-number of test environments and use the same sandbox certificate on all of them and it should work flawlessly.

We have been using 5 test environments and obviously 1 production environment since 5 years. We have same push certs deployed in all test environments and it work like charm!

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit difficult to realize what did you mean by multiple test environment. Did you mean, one for iOS and others for android, windows phone etc? surly not. If you mean iPhone, iPad etc then your one development APNS CERTIFICATE is enough for  testing(via sandbox). Another production APNS certificate is enough for App Store submission. Why need multiple? But there will be 2 certificate one is for application and    Another is for Push notification.